# Apache FOP 2.2 Include Fonts using Relative Path

Tags: java, kotlin, apache-fop

I'm setting up a `fop.xconf` and configuring which fonts are available to Apache FOP and would like to use a relative path rather than an absolute path:

```
<fop version="1.0">

    <strict-configuration>true</strict-configuration>
    <strict-validation>true</strict-validation>
    <base>./</base>
    <font-base>./</font-base>
    <source-resolution>72</source-resolution>
    <target-resolution>72</target-resolution>
    <default-page-settings height="11in" width="8.26in"/>

    <hyphenation-pattern lang="en" country="ZA">en_ZA</hyphenation-pattern>

    <renderers>
        <renderer mime="application/pdf">
        <fonts>
            <directory recursive="true">/Users/me/Code/company/project/src/main/resources/templates/fonts</directory>
            <substitutions>
                <substitution>
                    <from font-family="Helvetica" />
                    <to font-family="OpenSans" />
                </substitution>
            </substitutions>
        </fonts>
        </renderer>
   </renderers>    
</fop>
```

Is it possible to set that fonts directory inside renderers to use a relative path?

Or is possible to set it programmatically in which case I could make use of

```
this::class.java.getResource("/templates/fonts/MyFont.ttf")
```

to get the full path?

```
2017-10-24 05:24:48,591 WARN  org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent - The font directory ./fonts could not be found.
2017-10-24 05:24:48,591 WARN  org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent - The font directory ./templates/fonts could not be found.
2017-10-24 05:24:48,591 WARN  org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent - The font directory ./resources/templates/fonts could not be found.
```

Answer (score 2):

Although this is an old thread, I might add that even in FOP 2.3 the issue is still present. You might find [this FOP Bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FOP-2600) useful:

- font-base has been removed from config (not in the docs)
- use absolute paths

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this footnote in the FOP configuration documentation is the most helpful.

https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/configuration.html#fnref:1

It states that all relative paths in the configuration will resolve to the `<base>` path. In your case, it includes the `<font-base>`. Also, the last bit of the footnote states that if `<base>` is in itself a relative path, it will by default resolve to the current working directory.

Basically, there would be two approaches so that the `fonts` directory will be properly resolved and be found by FOP.

1. You can programmatically set the `<base>` path using the `FopFactory.setUserConfigBaseURI` API. That is if you're using Java.
2. If you're not using Java, you can set the  path relative to the current working directory, e.g. `<base>.</base>`, and within your program/script call a system function to change the current working directory to something that's known and will resolve the relative paths. Here's an example with PHP.

   ```
   // This would be in the PHP script.
   chdir("/var/www/html/site");
   exec("$path_to_fop -c $path_to_fop_xconf ...");

   // This would be how the <directory> element in fop.xconf would be written.
   // Since the current working directory is changed with chdir(), this should
   // resolve to /var/www/html/site/libraries/fop/fonts.
   <directory recursive="true">./libraries/fop/fonts</directory>
   ```

Comment: My FopFactory does not provide .setUserConfigBaseURI :( is there another solution for relative paths?

Answer (score 0):

put the URL = (/Users/me/Code/company/project/src/main/resources/templates/fonts) in `<font-base>./</font-base>` like this:

- `<font-base>/Users/me/Code/company/project/src/main/resources/templates/fonts</font-base>`

And you solve the problem! ;)

Comment: That's an absolute path though, not a relative path. I don't have the absolute path most of the time unfortunately.